# Getting error with pip search and pip install

Tags: python-3.x, pip

hi it is about two days I am getting this error:

**ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code:-32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.**

I asked from some people and searched a lot but I din't kbow what is the problem and how to fix it
I tryed `apt update` and `python3 pip install --upgrade pip` recommended by pip itself
I am in android using Termux
pip was working for some days ago...

Comment: It occures when I use  pip search or pip install commands for some modules

Comment: What exactly is your question? The explanation is right there in the quoted text – the API is disabled.

Comment: the question is basically that pip search is broken now, and what can we do to fix it. Answers show its probably not going to be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For search base on package name pattern, I share this script below, hope you find it useful.

```
#!/bin/bash
# pypi-search.sh 
# This script fetch data from https://pypi.org/simple/ 
# process the output for simple package name output with perl
# and then apply a regex pattern to the result

pypiurl=https://pypi.org/simple/
currentdate=$(date +%y%m%d)

cachedir=~/.cache/simple-pypi
[[ -d $cachedir ]] || mkdir -p $cachedir

cachefile=$(ls -1 $cachedir/*_simple-pypi.html 2>/dev/null | sort | head -n1)
[[ $cachefile = "" ]] && cachefile=$cachedir/"${currentdate}_simple-pypi.html"

searchpattern="$1"
cmd="$2"

if [[ -f $cachefile ]] ; then
    dbdate=$(echo $cachefile | grep -Po "[0-9]{6,6}")
    # if db is older than 3 days or second parameter is 'update'
    ( (( ($currentdate - $dbdate) > 3 )) || [[ "x$cmd"  = 'xupdate' ]] ) && {
        echo "last update was on : $dbdate"
        cachefile=$cachedir/"${currentdate}_simple-pypi.html"
        wget -q --show-progress -O - $pypiurl > $cachefile
    }
else
    wget -q --show-progress -O - $pypiurl > $cachefile
fi

[[ x$searchpattern = "x" ]] && read -p "Enter pypi name pattern : " searchpattern
perl -pe 's/.*([\/"]{1,1}\>){1,1}([^>]+(.*)[^<])+\<\/a\>/\2/g' $cachefile | grep -P "$searchpattern"
```

Usage:
pypi-search.sh ^pip$

Answer (score 127):

Sadly `pip search` is now permanently banned by [python.org](https://status.python.org/). 
They said that they are experiencing "hundreds of thousands of search calls per hour" for 100 days(since Nov 14, 2020), and the XMLRPC API, via which the search calls are taking, had already been determined to be deprecated before this happened.
So maybe we need to search for packages directly on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org), or turn to packages like [pypi-simple-search](https://github.com/jeffmm/pypi-simple-search) or [pipsearch](https://github.com/shubhodeep9/pipsearch).

Comment: Shouldn't they remove the `search` sub-command from `pip` as well? 

Comment: This was covered in *The Register*: https://www.theregister.com/2021/05/25/pypi_search_error/

Comment: @Meysam for long lasting, industry standard tooling you first issue a deprecation warning (ca be several years before the actual deprecation). You don't just go and remove stuff.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius But this is not a deprecation warning. The `search` sub-command is in fact deprecated since the API is disabled. The warning is just telling there was a sub-command there.

Comment: If the ban is permanent then the error message should be changed to say so. The present message is utterly unhelpful because it points to a page that implies that everything is ok. It would also be helpful if the naive/casual user is pointed toward a solution or work around like pip-search [link] ( https://www.dark-hamster.com/application/how-to-solve-error-message-error-xmlrpc-request-failed-code-32500-upon-executing-pip-search/)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius lol and yet they just went ahead an removed it on the server side to Meysam's point. If you're going to do that then you might as well remove pip search subcommand. This is different from legacy versions still obviously having the search subcommand. Makes absolutely no sense the way it is currently handled.

Comment: It would be trivial to replace the search command in pip with code equivilant to that @dorian posted below.  #forkpip

Comment: `pip search x-package-name` can be used with the `pip_search` package and an alias bash script described [here](https://github.com/victorgarric/pip_search) to the file where you inserted the script e.g. .bash_alias. Then just run `source ~/.bash_alias` and it will work immediately.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the link, in the last update they stated that the XMLRPC API is disabled (due to outrageous traffic). This means `pip search` is currently disabled.
The last update was posted one month ago, I can't see any change.

Comment: I saw that but I couldn't understand the reasondoes it mean it will not work any more? and do you think how can I fix it?

Comment: Yesm it means it won't come back. You can use the simple JSON search. I found this repo for this problem: https://github.com/jeffmm/pypi-simple-search
I think it works.

Comment: :( Does it mean I am banned from pip service? :(( thanks anyway

Comment: It means we're *all* banned. :(