# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpxpy'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I'm running a Jupyter notebook with the lines:

```
   import gpxpy 
   import gpxpy.gpx
```

and I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/kc/5p61t70n0llbn05934gj4r_w0000gn/T/ipykernel_37440/3640958118.py in <module>
----> 1 import gpxpy
      2 import gpxpy.gpx

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpxpy'
```

FWIW, doing the following on the terminal command line (macOS 16.6.4)

```
   $ pip3 search gpxpy
ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.
$
```

Don't know whether it's a conda environment problem or a problem with the gpxpy package itself.

Comment: This will explain why your `pip search` didn't work. Have you run `pip install gpxpy` from the right venv? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375972/getting-error-with-pip-search-and-pip-install

Comment: Thanks. On the command line (macOS terminal) I don't have pip accessible.
```$ pip search gpxpy
   -bash: pip: command not found
   $ python3 pip install --upgrade pip
   /opt/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I logged into anaconda.org, searched for module `gpxpy` and then did one of the recommended installs:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gpxpy
```

At least I got around the module load error.